# Eclipse cycling through tabs (end to start if next tab; start to end if prev tab)

Tags: eclipse, tabs, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

Inside eclipse I set up the keybinding like this:
Next Tab: Ctrl+Tab
Prev Tab: Ctrl+Shift+Tab

But when I am at the end of all tabs, I cannot cycle to the first tab by pressing the Next Tab key. How can I manage to do that?

I searched in the /Preferences->General->Keys for some additional options but I didn't find anything helpful.